# How to care for bent avocado tree

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, pruning, tree-care, avocado

I have an avocado tree I started from a pit. It has lived in upstate New York indoors and has grown tall and skinny. I recently moved to Atlanta, Georgia and so can have it outdoors more. The tree is somewhat crooked.

1. Should I prune it? (Possibly even cutting off the top half of the tree?)
2. Should I get a bigger pot?
3. Should I get some kind of system going to stabilize and/or straighten it out?
4. Should I keep it outside all of the time?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think pruning is necessary, but it might improve the form of the tree (make it more compact).
2. Yes, I would say 3-4 X larger! Or even bigger.
3. If you decide not to prune, a stake or pole is needed to support its weight. It is too long now and bends because of the weight.
4. I think the tree can be outside as long as there is no frost. I don't know the climate in Atlanta, but it sounds subtropic.

Comment: If I did decide to prune it (with the goal to make it more bushy), how would I do so? Just chop it off half way?

Comment: I would never chop off more than 1/3 of the plant. Here some [instructions](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/avocado/pruning-avocado-trees.htm).